# I am facing an issue when converting the datetime in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert date entered by the user as per the data entry format( `"dd/MM/YYYY"`, `"MM/dd/YYYY"`).

and am using `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo` for conversion so that the date conversion should be independent of my pc calender:

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfodd = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
dateInfodd.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfomm = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
dateInfomm.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

My pc-calender Format is : `MM-dd-YYYY`

Now whenever i convert date from `dd/MM/YYYY` to `MM/dd/YYYY`  or vice versa its convert as `MM-dd-YYYY`.

Example:  `24/08/2013 => 08-24-2013`.

I want to sustain the same date separator "/" after Conversion.

Waiting for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: What happened to your CAPS Lock key?

Comment: Have you tried .ToString(MM/dd/YYYY) ? That is if you are only trying to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` will be replaced by your actual culture's date-separator which seems to be `-`. So you need to provide `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
string result = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [**The "/" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   **localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified
>   culture**.

Comment: Someone is downvoting all answers, why?

Comment: An Example Program Would be Really Help Full.

Comment: @ABR: What have you problems with? The `DateTime.Parse` works? (if not, what input does the use provide?) Once you have the `DateTime` the code above works.

Answer (score 0):

In date format strings, the `/` character is not a literal but the [date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) configured for your current culture. Therefore, if your current date separator is `-`, all `/` characters will be replaced by `-`.

You can surround the character with single quotes to force it to be interpreted as a literal, for instance:

```
"dd'/'MM'/'YYYY"
```

Comment: @downvoter, could you explain what is wrong in my answer? Using single quotes does allow to use slash character literals regardless of the current culture.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why don't you use the `parseExact` method of `DateTime`? It would convert your value to the expected format and you will still be able to use it as a `DateTime`. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).